# How do I prove that a function with $f(x + y) \leq f(x)f(y)$ and $f(0) =1$ is continuous, if it is continuous in $x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Be $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function with $f(x + y) \leq f(x)f(y)$ and $f(0) = 1$.

If $f$ is continuous in $x = 0$, then it is continuous in all $\mathbb{R}$.

I have no idea how to prove this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I saw a similar case with equality between addition and multiplication but haven't been able to adjust it to this case. (in case anyone is interested: [Prove that if $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ and f is continuous in $ x=0$, then it is continuous in all its domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933246/prove-that-if-fxy-fxfy-and-f-is-continuous-in-x-0-then-it-is-contin))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $x, h \in \Bbb R$ we have the two inequalities
$$
 f(x+h) \le f(x) f(h) \, ,\\
 f(x) \le f(x+h) f(-h) \, .
$$
Now $f(-h) > 0$ for sufficiently small $h$, so that we can divide the second inequality by $f(-h)$ to get
$$
\frac{f(x)}{f(-h)} \le f(x+h) \le f(x) f(h) \, .
$$
Then $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = 1$ implies $\lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h) = f(x)$.

Comment: Could you explain two things a bit more? First, I don't understand why this is the case: $f(-h) > 0$ for sufficiently small $h$. Second, I don't understand the last line: why does $\lim_{h \to 0} f(h) = 1 \implies \lim_{h \to 0}f(x+h) = f(x)$?

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ with $f(0) = 1 > 0$. It follows that $f$ is strictly positive in some interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. – Then both $\frac{f(x)}{f(-h)}$ and $f(x)f(h)$ tend to $f(x)$ for $h \to 0$, and $f(x+h)$ is “squeezed” in between.